# Angular 5 load google chart

Tags: javascript, charts, angular5

I am trying to add google chart into my angular project. I am trying to use google chart by adding google chart js.

So I have create a angular app and I am have added google chart in my index.html:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BiharEconomy</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I am loading loader.js inside index.html and in my and inside component.html I am adding :

```
   <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

And I can show google chart by using this code inside my component.ts like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {


      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
       google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

       // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
       google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

       // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
       // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
       // draws it.
       function drawChart() {

         // Create the data table.
         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
         data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
         data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
         data.addRows([
           ['Mushrooms', 3],
           ['Onions', 1],
           ['Olives', 1],
           ['Zucchini', 1],
           ['Pepperoni', 2]
         ]);

         // Set chart options
         var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                        'width':400,
                        'height':300};
         // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
         var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
         chart.draw(data, options);
       }
```

Using these codes I can show google chart. So my question is how to use javascript codes into typescript. Is it possible to add these javascript codes inside typescript when I add this code outside ngOnInit() I am getting errors. What would be the best way to call these code under function

Answer (score 0):

replace var with let and declar google let.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare let google: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                ['Work',     11],
                ['Eat',      2],
                ['Commute',  2],
                ['Watch TV', 2],
                ['Sleep',    7]
            ]);

            let options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities'
            };

            let chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Chrome errors "google is not defined". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JensMander Add this in index.html just before the `</head>` tag: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`